# getting BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection error when performing insertMany using upsert

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

So i am trying to add multiple documents to mongo collection so i am using insertMany my use case is that if there is a document already present then it should get updated with the latest document so i am using upsert, but i am getting BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection  error. Below is the code which i am trying

```
  dbo.collection("formulas").insertMany(documents, { upsert: true, safe: false  })
```

and my document looks like this

> [ { _id: 5ede7f3a471f7751ee27c828,
> formula: '4yogesh',
> formula_alias: 'FGAFyogesh',
> formGroupDescription: null,
> formula_sequence_id: 2,
> selectedRulesetEvent: '',
> no_of_variables: 1,
> productId: 'newProd12345',
> productVersion: '1.0',
> coverageGroup: 'FGA',
> organisationId: 'org34',
> userKey: 'org34admin',
> formGroup: 'FGA',
> rulesetEventDropdown: '' } ]

Since i am new to mongo not sure what exactly is wrong, can someone please help. Any idea or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `insertMany`  - I don't see this supported upsert as mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/)
2. As you need to update if exists, you can use `updateMany`. But it sounds like you need to update if same id exists. So you need to prepare `UpdateOne`statements with `upsert` and use it in `bulkwrite`
3. About the error - you are trying to insert a doc with already existing unique key field. In this case, it's `_id`

Comment: @@ Gibbs can you please elaborate on the second point via example. I want to add the document if it does not exist in collection and if it exists then update the entire existing document with new document.

Comment: Update with upsert will work. To update multi doc with different conditions, use bulk write of update.

Comment: @@Gibbs can you please give an example since i am new to mongo

Comment: Sure. [Refer this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#UpdateOne-and-updateMany) pass _id as find command. Update as document you are passing. Upsert option as you already mentioned. If you want to replace instead update, look for replace One in mongo.

Comment: @@ Gibbs i think update with upsert should do the work but not sure about bulk write have to check more on this

Comment: You can play with that and post a question if you face any problem

Answer (score 0):

Faced this problem when try to update my DB from csv file:
I have csv with `_id` field like `641d8ff6f402d033ec8420c1` and got this error.

The problem was that Mongo doesn't understand string ids and create new ObjectId for each imported field.

The solution is use another potential key for identify updating records and pass it to the `mongoimport` command with `--upsertFields <fields>` [according doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#std-option-mongoimport.--upsertFields):

```
mongoimport --db testDb --collection test --mode merge --upsertFields keyField --file /test-import.csv
```